# XSLT code to get the value of an attribute of the last element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am XSLT beginner and  have an XML with the connections tags as mentioned below ..

This is my XML:

```
<connections sourceElement="/3/@elements.2" targetElement="/3/@elements.0" schemaName="Target_Query"/> 
<connections sourceElement="/3/@elements.1" targetElement="/3/@elements.3" schemaName="R3_DF_PRODUCT"/> 
<connections sourceElement="/3/@elements.3" targetElement="/3/@elements.2" schemaName="Transform3"/>
```

And I want to iterate through the connections and get only the last one

```
//dataflow:DataFlow/connections
```

(which `@targetElement` isn't used as `@SourceElement` in other `<connections>`).
I need to get the value of `@schemaName`.

Can any body help with the sample snippets to achieve this?

Comment: Will there only be one `DataFlow` element in your XML?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `schemaName` attribute of the last `connections` element, you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//dataflow:DataFlow/connections[last()]/@schemaName
```

IN XSLT it can be accessed with

```
<xsl:value-of select="//dataflow:DataFlow/connections[last()]/@schemaName"/>
```

**Output is:**

> Transform3